# youtube video not becoming responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have applied the following js to make youtube video become responsive.
Video are place in iframe
here is the script-:

```html
var $allVideos = $("iframe[src^='//player.vimeo.com'], iframe[src^='//www.youtube.com']"),

    $fluidEl = $(".newsblock_maintext");

$allVideos.each(function() {

  $(this)
    .data('aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)

    .removeAttr('height')
    .removeAttr('width');

});

$(window).resize(function() {

  var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();

  $allVideos.each(function() {

    var $el = $(this);
    $el
      .width(newWidth)
      .height(newWidth * $el.data('aspectRatio'));

  });

}).resize();
```

And my youtube video is given below which is placed in a "newsblock_maintext" div.

```html
<div class="newsblock_maintext"><p>Bekijk hier de nieuwe kijk op het wonen volgens MisuraEmme: "The way you are furniture for 24H life-style" zoals onlangs gepresenteerd is, tijdens de succesvolle Salone del Mobile 2015.</p><p><iframe width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8Ei0jelpeGQ"></iframe></p></div>
```

so what thing should i need to make this video responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iframe selector is returning null. you missing *https* in selector.

> $("iframe[src^='//player.vimeo.com'],
>   iframe[src^='//www.youtube.com']")

change

```
var $allVideos = $("iframe[src^='//player.vimeo.com'], iframe[src^='//www.youtube.com']")
```

to

```
var $allVideos = $("iframe")
```

or

```
var $allVideos = $("iframe[src^='//player.vimeo.com'], iframe[src^='https://www.youtube.com']")
```

working fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zpo1toe/)